# changing all cell values of a column by keeping only the 1st digit of its 3 digit name - R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I think the name if pretty self explanatory. Lets say i want to change the column `Zweck` so that the resulting column i obtain only contains the 1st digit of the cell content:

I basically want to reduce the cell content to its first digit. I have seen people using the function `sub` but i want able to implement it.

Any ideas for some simple solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substr` to extract the character based on the position

```
df1$Zweck <- as.integer(substr(df1$Zweck, 1, 1))
df1$Zweck
#[1] 2 2 2 2 2
```

If we look at the `?substr` the general Usage is

> substr(x, start, stop)

where `x` is a `vector, 'start' and 'end' arguments signify the starting position of character and ending position respectively